# Removing null values from map in pig script

Tags: apache-pig

This is the pig script

```
set default_parallel 100;
REGISTER '/x/home/eap/prod/lib/*.jar';
data = LOAD 'eap-prod://event' USING EAPDataLoader('{"attributes": { "all": "false",   "values" : ["customer_id","second_party_cookie_id","email_name","user_guid"] }}');

data_proj = foreach data generate eapVars.timestamp, attributes;

store data_proj into '/user/eap_test';
```

Here in the output, I am printing a map (attributes) which can have 4 values. 
Next step I have to do is just remove the keys in the output which have no values...

Currently the output is :

```
1392833008295[secondary_cookie_id#abcd,user_guid#,email_name#,customer_id#1234]
```

And I want it to be

```
1392833008295[secondary_cookie_id#abcd,customer_id#1234]
```

How do I get rid of the keys that have no values in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Write an UDF that iterate all the Map and delete the null values